# EXCEL: Chart not Updating when Value on Dropdown changes

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, dropdown

I created a chart which automatically updates ranges when data is added to the source table. I added a dropdown menu which tells the chart what data to display/show. My problem is, the chart doesnt automatically update when the dropdown value is changed, i need to press CTRL+SAVE for the data to match the value on the dropdown. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

here's an image of my graph. as you can see, the dropdown has three options. if i change the dropdown value, the chart wont update unless i press CTRL+S. Please note that I am not using vba/macro for this.

[image: here's an image of my graph. as you can see, the dropdown has three options. if i change the dropdown value, the chart wont update unless i press CTRL+S. Please note that I am not using vba/macro for this.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but maybe automatic calculation is off
[image: please check here]